# Incorrect syntax near '0'.: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [users].* FROM [users] OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @0 ROWS ONLY', N'@0 int', @0 = 1

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord, sql-server-2017, rails-5.1.6

I'm using rails 5.1.6 with activerecord-sqlserver-adapter 5.1.6, tiny_tds 2.1.2. and SQL Server 2017.

> Databaseaccess is OK,
>
> SQL (1.1ms)  USE [MIST_Test]
>
> User Load (1.5ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT  [users].* FROM
>   [users] OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @0 ROWS ONLY', N'@0 int', @0 = 1 
>   [["LIMIT", nil]]
>
> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: TinyTds::Error: Incorrect syntax near
>   '0'.: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT  [users].* FROM [users] OFFSET 0
>   ROWS FETCH NEXT @0 ROWS ONLY', N'@0 int', @0 = 1
>
> from
>   C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver/database_statements.rb:368:in
>   `each'
>
> Caused by TinyTds::Error: Incorrect syntax near '0'.
>
> from
>   C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver/database_statements.rb:368:in
>   `each'
>
> SQL Server needs an 'ORDER BY' to use the 'OFFSET' clause.

Can somebody help?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the query you are firing and exact use case?

Comment: In my rails user controller i am trying to find first record by using User.first its throws an  error as shown below.EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [users].* FROM [users] OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @0 ROWS ONLY', N'@0 int', @0 = 1

Comment: Is it specifically for User.first query or all queries? Can you please try User.all ?

Comment: User.all is displays  all records .currently we are upgrading rails 3.2 ruby(1.9.3) to rails 5.1.6(ruby2.5). rails active-record  session store its always throws offset issues. Our database is sql server 2017 with group managed account.adapter: sqlserver
  #username:  XXXXX$
  host: localhost
  Trusted_Connection: yes
  Integrated Security: true;

Comment: I have the same problem - went from Rails 4.2 / SQL Server 2008 to Rails 5.2 / SQL Server 2016 and get exactly the same error. 

User.find(1) => ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (TinyTds::Error: Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'.: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT  [Users].* FROM [Users] WHERE [Users].[idUsers] = @0  ORDER BY [Users].[idUsers] ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @1 ROWS ONLY', N'@0 int, @1 int', @0 = 1, @1 = 1)

Interestingly when I connect to SQL Server 2016 with Rails 4.2 this error goes away, so it's likely related to a change in the ActiveRecord / SQLServer Adapter or tinytds layer.